# $AB-AA^TABB^TA^Tvv^TAB$ is not full rank

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

My question is very simple.

$A \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 3}, B \in \mathbb R^{3 \times 3}, v \in \mathbb R^{2 \times 1}$

I'm looking for matrices $A,B,v$ of the dimensions above, such that:

a) $AB$ has full row rank.

b) The matrix $AB-AA^TABB^TA^Tvv^TAB$ does not have full row rank.

I've been looking for an example like that for a while, beginning to think maybe one doesn't exist.

Anyone care to try find an example?

Comment: When you say $AB$ has full row rank, you mean two?

Comment: I do. It's entirely possible that if $AB$ has rank $2$ then $AB-AA^TABB^TA^Tvv^TAB$ also must have rank 2. A proof eludes me. I'm looking for either a counter example or a proof.

Comment: Because of $vv^T$, the second term has rank at most $1$.

Comment: That's correct. That does not say anything about the summation of the two terms.

Comment: Exodd beat me to it but you can think of the problem as having two terms $C=AB$ and $uw^T$ where $u=AA^TABB^TA^Tv$, $w^T=v^TAB$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $AB-AA^TABB^TA^Tvv^TAB = (I-AA^TABB^TA^Tvv^T)AB$ and the eigenvalues of $AA^TABB^TA^Tvv^T$ are $0$ and $v^TAA^TABB^TA^Tv$, so it is enough that
$v^TAA^TABB^TA^Tv = 1$

In order to find the simplest example, take $B=I$ and
$$
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so in this case, $v^TAA^TABB^TA^Tv = v^Tv$ and any norm one $v$ is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

**Example:**
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0}, \quad B = \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1}, \quad v = \pmatrix{1\\0}.
$$
We find that $AB$ has full rank, but
$$
AB-AA^TABB^TA^Tvv^TAB = A - AA^Tv(A^Tv)^T = \pmatrix{0&0&0\\0&1&0}
$$
does not.